# Spark generate a rank on specific field of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ranking

I have already got a `rdd` as caculation result let's say it's as following format:

```
(uid, factor, name, avatar, gender, otherFactor1, otherFactor2)
```

And now I want the RDD to be sorted by `factor` and make a field like `rank` which indicates the rank of the record and later on use a foreach to write every record to the DB

I know I *might* do this by:

```
rdd.sortBy{
   case (uid, factor, name, avatar, gender, otherFactor1, otherFactor2) => {
       factor
   }
}.foreach{
   //how could I insert a rank field by the index of the loop?
}
```

And here I am stuck by how to add the `rank` field by the foreach loop's index

any idea?

Comment: `rdd.sortBy(_._2).zipWithIndex`?

Comment: @philantrovert, answer the question below :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Done. OP can close the question now.

Comment: armnotstring, accept and upvote @philantrovert's answer below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
rdd.sortBy(_._2).zipWithIndex
```

You can flatten it to a more decent structure using :

```
rdd.sortBy(_._2).zipWithIndex.map { 
    case ((uid, factor, name, avatar, gender, otherFactor1, otherFactor2), rank) =>
    (uid, factor, name, avatar, gender, otherFactor1, otherFactor2, rank)
}
```

One thing you might want to note about `zipWithIndex`, from [the source code for RDD.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1282)

> This method needs to trigger a spark job when this RDD contains more than one partitions.

If you want to avoid that, you can use `zipWithUniqueId` but I don't think it gives contiguous indices for each element.

Answer (score 0):

See if below can be helpful.

```
case class ItemInfo(item:String, quantity:Int)
val data = sc.parallelize(List(("a",10),("b",20),("c",30)))
val ItemDF = data.map(x=> ItemInfo(x._1,x._2)).toDF()
ItemDF.registerTempTable("Item_tbl")
val rankedItems = sqlContext.sql("select item, quantity, rank() over(order by quantity desc) as rank from Item_tbl")
rankedItems.collect().foreach(println)
```

This example ranks the item based on quantity.

Comment: sorry, haven't try hive way with spark sql yet, 'zipWithIndex' as commented by @philantrovert will do the trick